# Replace multiple characters in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Is there a simple way in python to replace multiples characters by another?

For instance, I would like to change:

```
name1_22:3-3(+):Pos_bos
```

to

```
name1_22_3-3_+__Pos_bos
```

So basically replace all `"(",")",":"` with `"_"`.

I only know to do it with:

```
str.replace(":","_")
str.replace(")","_")
str.replace("(","_")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is usage of so-called *list comprehension* combined with so-called *ternary conditional operator* following way:

```
text = 'name1_22:3-3(+):Pos_bos '
out = ''.join(['_' if i in ':)(' else i for i in text])
print(out) #name1_22_3-3_+__Pos_bos
```

As it gives `list`, I use `''.join` to change `list` of characters (`str`s of length 1) into `str`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to replace multiple characters with one pattern:

```
import re
s = 'name1_22:3-3(+):Pos_bos '
re.sub(r'[():]', '_', s)
```

**Output**

```
'name1_22_3-3_+__Pos_bos '
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a translation table. In Python 2, `maketrans` is defined in the `string` module.

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans("():", "___")
```

In Python 3, it is a `str` class method.

```
>>> table = str.maketrans("():", "___")
```

In both, the table is passed as the argument to `str.translate`.

```
>>> 'name1_22:3-3(+):Pos_bos'.translate(table)
'name1_22_3-3_+__Pos_bos'
```

---

In Python 3, you can also pass a single `dict` mapping input characters to output characters to `maketrans`:

```
table = str.maketrans({"(": "_", ")": "_", ":": "_"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Sticking to your current approach of using `replace()`:

```
s =  "name1_22:3-3(+):Pos_bos"
for e in ((":", "_"), ("(", "_"), (")", "__")):
    s = s.replace(*e)
print(s)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
name1_22_3-3_+___Pos_bos
```

**EDIT**: (for readability)

```
s =  "name1_22:3-3(+):Pos_bos"
replaceList =  [(":", "_"), ("(", "_"), (")", "__")]

for elem in replaceList:
    print(*elem)          # : _, ( _, ) __  (for each iteration)
    s = s.replace(*elem)
print(s)
```

**OR**

```
repList = [':','(',')']   # list of all the chars to replace
rChar = '_'               # the char to replace with
for elem in repList:
    s = s.replace(elem, rChar)
print(s)
```